How do I convert an image from PNG to BMP in Delphi VCL?
When I convert PNG picture to BMP picture via the routine below, then the colors are not the same in BMP as they are in the original PNG.
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  Png: TPngImage;
begin
  Png := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    Png.LoadFromFile('C:\temp\Source.png');
    bmp := TBitmap.Create(Png.Width, Png.Height);
    try
      R := Rect(0, 0, Png.Width, Png.Height);
      bmp.Canvas.CopyRect(R, png.Canvas, R);
      bmp.SaveToFile('C:\temp\target.bmp')
    finally
      Bmp.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Png.Free;
  end;
end;

Could you provide me a hint on how to solve this issue, please?

It's probably because you did not define the bitmap's PixelFormat or Palette before drawing the PNG onto the bitmap. If you Assign() the TPNGImage to the TBitmap, it will set the bitmap's PixelFormat to match the PNG's pixel bit depth, and if the PNG has a color palette defined then it will be copied into the TBitmap.

I just tested the following procedure and it works without any issues. The colors look identical to my human eyes when comparing the original PNG and the result BMP:
procedure ConvertPNGtoBMP(const PNGFileName, BMPFileName: string);
begin
  var PNG := TPNGObject.Create;
  var BMP := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    PNG.LoadFromFile(PNGFileName); // Load the PNG image
    BMP.Assign(PNG); // Assign the PNG image to the BMP object
    BMP.SaveToFile(BMPFileName); // Save the BMP image
  finally
    PNG.Free;
    BMP.Free;
  end;
end;

Results:

I simply called it like this:
ConvertPNGtoBMP('MyPhoto.png', 'MyPhoto.bmp');


Hi your code works, thank you
